# Assistance with Code for access to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

Not to inconvenience anyone unnecessarily, but, I have done much searching on the internet and still cannot find the exact answer. There are MANY similar examples, but nothing exact (Must be because my coding is pretty ... bad)

To be brief, I have a MySQL Db and all the relevant tables (plus) scripts for view all, edit & delete records..... What I don't have is a 'search' page using a text box, which can search my Db using a specific "13" digit number like (6125478215017).

The scripts that I have all work when searching for the "First name" or "Last name" but I really need the search based on a number. I would be happy with a simple php page. If anyone has code for this, I would be VERY HAPPY.

SORRY, CODE IS:

```
?php  
/* call this script "advs.php" */ 
if(!$c) {  
?> 
<form action="advs.php?c=1" method=POST> 
<b>Find Results with: </b><br> 
Any of these words: <input type="text" length=40 name="any"> <br> 
All of these words: <input type="text" length=40 name="all"> <br> 
None of these words: <input type="text" length=40 name="none"> <br> 
<input type="submit" value="Search"> 
</form> 
<? 
} else if($c) { 
MySQL_connect("localhost", "afr", "kiap"); 
MySQL_select_db("afrdatabase"); 
if((!$all) || ($all == "")) { $all = ""; } else { $all = "+(".$all.")"; } 
if((!$any) || ($any == "")) { $any = ""; }  
if((!$none) || ($none == "")) { $none = ""; } else { $none = "-(".$none.")"; } 
$query = " 

SELECT *, 
MATCH(title, story) AGAINST ('$all $none $any' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score  
FROM users  
WHERE MATCH(title, story) AGAINST ('$all $none $any' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"; 
$artm1 = MySQL_query($query); 
if(!$artm1) {  
echo MySQL_error()."<br>$query<br>";  
} 
echo "<b>Article Matches</b><br>"; 
if(MySQL_num_rows($artm1) > 0) { 
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Score </td><td>Title </td><td>Body</td></tr>"; 
while($artm2 = MySQL_fetch_array($artm1)) { 
$val = round($artm2['score'], 3); 
$val = $val*100; 
echo "<tr><td>$val</td>"; 
echo "<td>{$artm2['title']}</td>"; 
echo "<td>{$artm2['body']}</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
} 
else {  
echo "No Results were found in this category.<br>";  
} 
echo "<br>";  
} 

?>
```

Comment: Need specifics. Show us what you have, what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

send a query like `SELECT first_name, last_name, thirteen_digit_number FROM mytable WHERE thirteen_digit_number = 6125478215017`

[updated] so if you want the whole row, use `SELECT *`. it appears you already know how to format the result into HTML, so what more do you need from the community?

Comment: Are you sure. Is **=** will help to search.OP talking about search not checking correct value

Comment: he said "using a specific 13 digit number", so I'm assuming he knows what he wants.

Comment: correct, I will have a specific 13 digit number. If I search using the 13 digit number, I would like it to reflect the 'row' in the Db, which should then display: Peter | Smith | 6254124587021 | peter@dim.com |

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `LIKE '%612547%'`

```
SELECT *  FROM `tbl_number` WHERE `number` LIKE '%612547%'
```

Need more specifics for better answer.

Comment: each 13 digit number is unique (say ... something like a social security number)